# SSH's -t option - how do I remotely execute a complex command that includes pipes and variable expansion?

Tags: bash, ssh, pipe, variable-substitution

The following script is run by `root` and is meant to share two directories from jim's computer to that of oumaima.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

au=$(echo "$(head -n 1 /etc/doas.conf)"|sed 's/permit//;s/as//;s/root//;s/ //g') 

dirs=(
"/var/lib/transmission-daemon/downloads"
"/home/${au}/VisualArts/films_FR"
)



dst_ip="[fe80::cc08:9467:8dba:15a9%wlp4s0]"
her_host="fe80::cc08:9467:8dba:15a9%wlp4s0"

give_oumaima() {
for d in ${dirs[@]}; do 
  rsync -e "ssh -6 -i /home/${au}/.ssh/id_rsa" -av --delete --no-o --no-g --chown=oumaima:oumaima "${d}" "root@${dst_ip}:/home/oumaima/Desktop" &&
  ssh -i "/home/${au}/.ssh/id_rsa" -t -6 "root@${her_host}"  'echo -e "${d} synced, $(date)."|tee -a "/root/syncing-w-${au}.log"'
done
}

give_oumamima
```

The log file, `/root/syncing-w-.log`,  gets created in on the remote host and it content is:

```
 synced, Fri Dec  8 20:05:15 CET 2023.
 synced, Fri Dec  8 20:52:57 CET 2023.
 synced, Fri Dec  8 20:52:58 CET 2023.
 synced, Fri Dec  8 21:01:37 CET 2023.
```

The variables such as `au` and `d` do not expand to `jim` (the admin user of my PC) and the name of the directory. This results long being created as `/root/syncing-w-.log` instead of `/root/syncing-w-jim.log`. Also the content of the log is not specific with regards to the directory being copied by `rsync`.
It seems that single quotes are the culprit but how might I rewrite `'echo -e "${d} synced, $(date)."|tee -a "/root/syncing-w-${au}.log"'` so that the variables do expand?

Comment: Your issue has nothing to do with and is not affected in any way by the `-t` option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answering the particular question

Things inside single quotes don't get expanded. So you need to use double quotes. Once they have been expanded once you don't want them expanded a second time, so you probably want to swap the single and double quotes to get

```
    "echo -e '${d} synced, $(date).'|tee -a '/root/syncing-w-${au}.log'"
```

which will run the date command on your computer, expand d and au on your computer and will pass something like

```
    echo -e '/var/lib/transmission synced, Fri 8 Dec 2023 23:45.'|tee -a '/root/syncing-w-jim.log'
```

to the remote computer to be executed.

### A different approach

Do local things locally and remote things remotely!

```
echo -e "${d} synced, $(date)." | ssh -i "/home/${au}/.ssh/id_rsa" -t -6 "root@${her_host}" tee -a "/root/syncing-w-${au}.log"
```

You can do the echo on your machine and the tee on the remote.

### Answering the  general question

You should attempt to avoid running complicated commands on the remote machine via the command line. Write a shell script which is stored on the remote machine and execute it instead.

Comment: Or sometimes a good alternative for command(s) that _don't_ need terminal interation is to construct the command(s) and pipe them to, or read them as a heredoc by, `ssh` (without `-t`) so in either case they become stdin to the remote shell.